# How to align title html div with chart horizontally in highchart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

Consider the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7y1zp43/)

[image]

I am trying to align the gap between title `bottom-border` and the chart. Preferably the left side and right side of the chart aligns with the left side and right side of title border respectively.

Is there anyway I can do that without hardcoding (my chart width changes relative to screen size)?

Comment: Do you want to use the title `div` only for rendering this vertical line?

Comment: @KamilKulig I want a title plus bottom border, but currently I can't seems to get the bottom border to align with the chart below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the title to have the same width and left offset as the plot area. To make sure it's responsive use the `render` event:

```
chart: {
  plotBorderWidth: 1,
  events: {
    render: function() {
      var style = this.title.element.style;
      style.left = this.plotLeft + 'px';
      style.width = this.plotWidth + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

**Live working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/y3fj6vpq/

**API reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Answer (score -1):

Change these two properties of the title.

```
left: 77px;
width: 922px;
```

Comment: I don't want to hard code it since the chart is responsive to screen size